# equivalent statements about fully idempotent

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with identity. Show that the following are equivalent:

(a) $R$ is fully idempotent (that is, $I^2 = I$ for every ideal $I$ in $R$);

(b) for ideals $I$ and left ideals $A$ in $R$, we have $A \cap I \subset AI$;

(c) for ideals $I$ and left ideals $A$ in $R$ with $A \subset I$, we have $A \subset AI$.

(b) $\Rightarrow$ (c) is clearly.

(c) $\Rightarrow$ (b) Let $I$ be an ideal and $A$ a left ideal in $R$. Then $A \cap I$ is a left ideal in $R$ with $A \cap I \subset I$. It follows from (c) that
$$A \cap I \subset (A \cap I)I \subset AI.$$

(c) $\Rightarrow$ (a) Let $I$ be an ideal in $R$. It follows from (c) that $I \subset I^2$. Since always $I^2 \subset I$, we have $I = I^2$. So $R$ is fully idempotent.

But I can't prove that (a) $\Rightarrow$ (b). Can somebody help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A\subseteq I$, then $AR\subseteq I$. Now $AR$ is an ideal. Assuming (a), $A\subseteq AR=(AR)^2\subseteq ARI=AI$

This shows (a) implies (c), completing your equivalence.

Comment: (a) says that $I^2 = I$ for every "ideal" $I$, but $A$ is just a left ideal, NOT ideal. Why we have $A^2 = A$?

Comment: @EnyaHsu indeed, I missed that the first time. I adjusted: it’s still just a computation.  Thanks for letting me know I misread it.